# Delphi 10.2 - How to remove the Upcoming Events panel from the Welcom Page?

Tags: delphi, delphi-10.2-tokyo

Is there a way to customize the Welcom Page? In particular I'd like to hide the Upcoming Events panel.
Here are a fiew questions about hiding the Welcome Page altogether, and I'd prefer to just remove the Upcoming Events panel if it's possible.

Comment: I too find this Welcome Page and the Upcoming Events panel - and their browser random popup - to be *very* annoying!

Comment: You might also be interested in the plugin “Wuppdi“ from Daniel Wolf, in case you don't have write access to the mentioned default.htm.
[Wuppdi](https://www.danielwolf.eu/blog/2015/1668-meine-vorstellung-einer-willkommens-seite) (German!)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The *Welcome Page* is just a HTML page located in the *Welcomepage* subfolder of your Delphi installation.

To remove the Upcoming Events panel make sure you have write permission to the *default.htm* file in that folder. Then open *default.htm* in an editor, remove the *div class="feedPanel"* block and save the file.

In case your IDE setting is not set to English edit the *default.htm* in the folder of your current language setting.

Comment: Thank you very much Uwe!